# exploring zip archive by PHP

Tags: php, zip

this my code

```
$z = new ZipArchive();

if ($z->open('file.zip')) {

            for ($i=0; $i<$z->numFiles;$i++) {
                $aZipDtls = $z->statIndex($i);
                echo $aZipDtls['name'].'<br>';

            }
     }
```

it returns

```
docs/
docs/INSTALL.html
docs/auth_api.html
docs/install/
docs/install/index.htm
```

but i want it return a files tree like that

```
docs/
 -INSTALL.html
 -auth_api.html
  install
   -index.htm
```

to make it ul and li
and i want to do this do use the [PHP File Tree](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/projects/php/phpFileTree/phpFileTree-1.0.zip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to work that out manually. The zip archive stores the files in a very flat structure, but has knowledge of the structure required when "unzipping".

You will have to work out this structure as you go through the archive. You will need to take a look a string functions to help you do this:

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php

Comment: this mean there is no way to so that?

Comment: you can achieve what you want, you just have to code it yourself as there is no built in function for that.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use this library, I think it supports listing content.
http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/man/en/index.php